# Trying to access a custom prop in styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Hi I'm trying to access a custom prop in a styled-component.I know that this is a very basic thing but I can't figure it out. I think that it has something to do with the way how I access my theme.

It does not throw any error but the margin-bottom value is just not showing up in the printed css.

Can you point me in a direction? Thanks!

```
import StyledWrapper from './productCardStyles';

<StyledWrapper spaceBelow={spaceBelow}>
    hello world 
</StyledWrapper>


//productCardStyles.js
export default styled('div')(
  ({ theme }) => `
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: ${props => (props.spaceBelow ? '25px' : '0')};
`);
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using ThemeProvider in the higher order component. You can access theme by just using props.theme...

Update your productCardStyles.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const wrapper = styled.div`
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: ${props => (props.spaceBelow ? '25px' : '0')};
  color: ${props => props.theme.primaryColor}   // to access theme
`
```

export default wrapper

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you! Would you mind explaining why I was accessing the theme values in my original way blocking access to my custom props?